# DC current distance

Tags: power-supply, power, dc

May a DC current be transferred to long distances?

The idea is that I have several LED panels (each be driven by a DC 5 volts - 300 mA), each one must have a power supply circuit to convert 220VAC to 5VDC..

I want to reduce the costs of several power supply circuits by driving all the LED panels out of one single power supply, that means transferring 5VDC - 300 mA to long distance (about 50 meters)..

Could you please make it clear for me to understand if that's possible ?

Comment: If it is 300mA per panel and you have multiple panels you won't be able to distributed a stiff 5V bus economically (need large AWG wires)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlikely because the resistance of the cable feeding the display might be a couple of ohms and, at 300 mA this means only 4.4 volts at the display.

The way this is normally done is to feed maybe 9 volts and have a local voltage regulator at the display. A volt lost down the cable isn't a big deal any more because the local regulator will still produce 5 volts.

Comment: That's great.. Could you please tell me the formula to calculate the volts drop for a given distance ?

Comment: You decide on the cable, look at the specification, estimate the loop resistance for 50 metres and use ohms law to determine volt drop.

Comment: Got it.. the last question, what if the regulator failed ? the current will continue to flow with a non regulated voltage that can destroy the LEDs?

Comment: Correct, if the regulator failed short circuit. Unlikely but possible. It's more likely to fail open circuit of course but now you are into reliability engineering and this involves a lot of analysis of transients and protection methods. Beyond the scope of your question and current knowledge but I encourage you to think about it.

Comment: Note that an LED module specified to take 5 V likely has a regulator internally. Quite likely it will accept some range of voltages like 4.5 to 6 V and still work well. In this case, you could likely get away with supplying 5.5 V or so at the source and allow anything from 0 to 1 V drop in the wires. Check the datasheet for your LED module.